# LINQ to SQL getting Type and Length

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've been tasked with finding the Type and Length of a specific column from the DBML.

I would like to pass in the DataContext, TableName and then ColumnName to return my values that I'm looking for.  I found the following example of something similar, but it isn't returning anything:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27392/Using-the-LINQ-ColumnAttribute-to-Get-Field-Length

However, I may be implementing this incorrectly.  for the `obj` parameter should I pass in the DataContext?  I've found that when I try to load up the `info` (object array) I get nothing...

```
    public static int GetLengthLimit(object obj, string field)
    {
        int dblenint = 0;   // default value = we can't determine the length

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(field);


        // Find the Linq 'Column' attribute
        // e.g. [Column(Storage="_FileName", DbType="NChar(256) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        object[] info = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true);
        // Assume there is just one
        if (info.Length == 1)
        {
            ColumnAttribute ca = (ColumnAttribute)info[0];
            string dbtype = ca.DbType;

            if (dbtype.StartsWith("NChar") || dbtype.StartsWith("NVarChar") || dbtype.StartsWith("VarChar"))
            {
                int index1 = dbtype.IndexOf("(");
                int index2 = dbtype.IndexOf(")");
                string dblen = dbtype.Substring(index1 + 1, index2 - index1 - 1);
                int.TryParse(dblen, out dblenint);
            }
        }
        return dblenint;
    }
```

Comment: the object is an object of a Table-type. Look at the example you provided with the linq. object is for example customer = new Customer() where Customer is a table. and the field is for example "Name". Then you look for column-length of the Name column in the Customer table.

Answer (score 0):

No you pass an instance of one of the entities.

I would actually change that to take a `Type` as a parameter, not an instance.

Comment: I'm new to this Linq to Sql.  You mentioned entities...  We aren't using EF yet.  Does this change the answer any?

Comment: @JeffV no, i'm just saying the model classes that are generated - "entities" in the general sense.

Comment: I hate to be a newb on this, but could I ask you to explain a bit more?  Maybe with a code sample.  I'm sorry, I wish I knew what you were referencing...  I just don't at this time.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffV the object that represent your tables, `Users`, `Locations`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a given entity, This method will generate a dictionary of string fields' length (LinqToSQL syntax):

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetStrFieldsLen()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dicFieldLen = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var myEntity = new myEntity();

    foreach(var m in myEntity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var typeName = myEntity.GetType().GetProperty(m.Name).PropertyType;
        int iLen = 0;

        if (typeName == typeof(string))
        {
            var tv= (m.CustomAttributes).First().NamedArguments.ToArray()[0].TypedValue.ToString(); // Get DbType member

             int idxStart = tv.LastIndexOf("(") + 1;
             if (int.TryParse(tv.Substring(idxStart, tv.LastIndexOf(")") - idxStart), out iLen)==false)
                iLen= int.MaxValue; // Field length is MAX

             dicFieldLen.Add(m.Name, iLen);
         }
    }
    return dicFieldLen ;
}
```